# Create commonly used method for asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to create a function that can be called by multiple different pages in asp.net?

Say for example I have a method that takes two int parameters and adds them together and spits out the result

```
public int test(int a, int b)
{
     return a+b;
}
```

If I wanted to use this function on three different pages, how would I do it?

notes:
using C#
.NET 4
Entity Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method can be made static and you can put such methods into a static class like this.

```
public static class Utils
{

    public static int test(int a, int b)
    {
         return a+b;
    }

}
```

can call it from any page.

```
int result = Utils.test(someA, someB);
```

The other option is, if it's some page oriented function, you could create your own class that extends `Page` class and add function there and if you make all your pages extend this custom class, the functions will be available.

```
public class MyPage : Page
{

    public int test(int a, int b)
    {
         return a+b;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, exactly what I was after.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two options that make the most sense to me would be to:

1. Create a public static class like `Common` or `Utils`.
2. Create a `BasePage` that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`, and have your three pages inherit from the BasePage, which contains your test() method.

Answer (score 1):

This method can be made static and you can put such methods into a static class like this.

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static int test(int a, int b)
    {
         return a+b;
    }
}
```

can call it from any page:

```
int result = Utils.test(someA, someB);
```